# Nextjs throws React has detected a change in the order of Hooks even though from top level call

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I am using SWR to fetch some data from my database, but receiving this error message:

```
    Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by OrganizationSettings. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks
    
       Previous render            Next render
       ------------------------------------------------------
    1. useContext                 useContext
    2. useRef                     useRef
    3. useRef                     useRef
    4. useRef                     useRef
    5. useRef                     useRef
    6. useRef                     useRef
    7. useRef                     useRef
    8. useMemo                    useMemo
    9. useCallback                useCallback
    10. useSyncExternalStore      useSyncExternalStore
    11. useRef                    useRef
    12. useCallback               useCallback
    13. useCallback               useCallback
    14. useLayoutEffect           useLayoutEffect
    15. useLayoutEffect           useLayoutEffect
    16. useLayoutEffect           useLayoutEffect
    17. useDebugValue             useDebugValue
    18. undefined                 useContext
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

at OrganizationSettings (webpack-internal:///./components/organization/OrganizationSettings.tsx:21:86)
    at SettingsPage
    at section
```

Nevertheless I am following that I should only call hooks at top level and in a functional component. Check my code:

```
const OrganizationSettings = () => {
  const { data, isLoading, isError } = useOrganization();
  if (isError) return <LoadingError />;
  if (isLoading) return <LoadingSpinner />; 

  return (
    <Box bg={useColorModeValue('gray.50', 'inherit')} p={10} borderRadius="lg">
      <Box mt={[10, 0]}>
        {/* Commented out for readability */}
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default OrganizationSettings;
```

According to the error it fails after the line 21 which is after `if (isLoading) return <LoadingSpinner />;`

Do you have any ideas what I am doing wrong or what I am missing? This doesn't make sense, since the App also works fine and I do receive the data + the App renders correctly.

Comment: What about `useColorModeValue` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using a hook directly in the render, and it's not being rendered sometimes based on the conditions above.

The error message only shows the built-in hooks, so that is why you see `useContext` listed and not the `useColorModeValue`, but underneath this hook must be using context.

Using hooks this way is a bad practice for this exact reason. It works fine, but only under certain conditions, making the code unstable.

Move the hooks above any possible return statement.

```
const OrganizationSettings = () => {
  const bg = useColorModeValue('gray.50', 'inherit');
  const { data, isLoading, isError } = useOrganization();
  if (isError) return <LoadingError />;
  if (isLoading) return <LoadingSpinner />; 

  return (
    <Box bg={bg} p={10} borderRadius="lg">
      <Box mt={[10, 0]}>
        {/* Commented out for readability */}
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Comment: That did the trick. I somehow missed that hook and was already blind at this point. Thanks for pointing it out!